# How it's possible prove the following lemma?

Tags: geometry

Let $a$ and $b$ be two points and suppose $d(a,b)$ is distance between two points $a,b$.  The common intersection of the two closed discs,
each of radius $d(a, b)$, centered at $a$ and $b$, is called the lune of $(a,b)$, and is
denoted lune$(a, b)$.

Let $a, b, c$ and $d$ be four points in the plane in general position such
that $d(c, d) > d(a, b)$. If $d$ and $c$ both lie in lune$(a,b)$, then the line segments
$ab$ and $cd$ intersect.

I found the above lemma in the paper from Suri et al. But I seek for proving it because the paper doesn't contains its proof.

In essence I seek for an example that show why the lemma is true.

Comment: Think of the lune of (a,b) as two [Reuleaux triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) of diameter d(a,b). The two points c,d cannot lie in the same Reuleaux triangle, so there must be one point in each.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain by an example?

Comment: The inequality leads to the interaction - if c,d are in same lune, if there is intersection is between a and b.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Can you draw an example? Thank you

Comment: @Moti Can you draw an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.-Let $A,B$ the two symmetric upper and lower regions respectively inside the lune.(both regions are separated by the segment $\overline{ab})$. If
$\overline{cd}\gt\overline{ab}$ then necessarily the points $c$ and $d$ are in distinct regions $A$ and $B$

[image]